# F5 stopped working in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I am using SQLServer 2008 R2 Management Studio (10.50.2500.0) on Windows 7.

Suddenly the keyboard shortcut for execute query stopped working. The CTRL-E command still works but it's really anoying since I'm so used to F5. In the query menu the F5 command is replaced by CTRL+E.

[image]

My keyboard does not have an F-key lock button and the other F-keys are working. I have even tried using the on-screen keyboard so it's not related to my keyboard.

I think the problems started after an system update from Microsoft Update. How can i change it back? Cant find any options for remapping keys in SSMS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution:
Goto folder:

C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings
You will see there file named like:

CurrentSettings-2011-11-28.vssettings

Find and erase there following line:

```
<RemoveShortcut Command="Query.Execute" Scope="SQL Query Editor">F5</RemoveShortcut>
```

**EDIT:**
Don forget to restart ssms after doing the above changes

Comment: Found the row and removed it. Did unfortunately not fix my issue. Even tried rebooting after the change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just restarted SSMS again and now it gave me the "Please wait while configuring for the first time..." message. When it was done my beloved F5 is back! I have not tried anything else so i must assume it was this change that kicked in.

Comment: Ok. - that was it. I forgot to write that you have to re-start SSMS. :)

Comment: I actually did. Many times, including full OS restarts. Kicked in after i started SSMS the third time. Thanks.

Comment: Might be related to cacheing or something of my profile since its a network profile.

Answer (score 22):

I had similar issue and realized it was "F Lock" key issue. Make sure your F Lock key is on.

Comment: Had the same issue here, I'm using a Samsung Series 9, one of many laptops which utilize a Fn Lock.

Comment: Same issue on my Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this type of problem on my computer by hitting the FLock key, or Function Lock. Then my F5 key was back to normal, so I could easily run stored procedures.

Answer (score 5):

Check that results are set to "Results to grid" (CTRL+ D) and not set to "Results to File"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It seemed to appear when ViEmu plugin for SSMS remove loads of shortcuts that conflict with Vi. I later removed ViEmu but but shortcuts weren't restored. When I create a new .vssettings file (by removing the old one and then starting/stopping SSMS), then the shortcuts are still missing. It looks like it is picking up a template of shortcuts to remove when creating vssettings (it would be great if somebody had ideas on that)

I eventually hacked it by removing the <RemoveShortcuts> tags from inside the <UserShortcuts> tag in the vssettings file.

Now it works as before.